# How do I count the number of times a row contains two specific words

Tags: excel

I am trying to put together a sales spreadsheet for my boss that counts how many times a specific sales rep has closed a deal.  One column would have a sales rep name, and another column would have the status of the customer.

So what I want is a total of how many times columns D (Sales Rep) and E (Status) contain both `Condie` and `Closed`.

I know you can use Len to count words, but I only want to count them if both D and E contain the necessary data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Excel 2007+ use COUNTIFS

Answer (score 0):

To get the count of "Closed" sales made by a sales rep, write the formula below in the cells of a new column, and then sum such new column.

```
 =IF(AND(D2=salesRep,E2="Closed"),1,0)
```

The above assumes that you insert the name of the sale rep in a cell called: salesRep